# Bootstrap Datepicker not displaying correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi Ive put in a bootstrap date picker on my asp.net mvc form.
Ive set it up so it starts displaying years from a decade.

But the date picker only displays the years as one longer string, its functional though

```html
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startDate: "-120y",
        endDate: "-10y",
        startView: 2,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        defaultViewDate: { year: 1975, month: 01, day: 01 }
    });
    </script>
    }
```

Helper in view

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "01/12/80" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

What it should look like:

[image]

What it actually looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please show us what it displays and what you expect it to display.

Comment: added two screen shots

Comment: If you don't have any script errors and from the looks of the screenshot it appears the component is working normally. I'd check the css resources now.

Comment: What exactly am I looking and where please?

Comment: To start, did you load the datepicker's css resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jasen has pointed out i'd missed the css resource I'm the bundle config. Thanks